# Storing $_POST data to local db then sending it to Salesforce via web to lead form

Tags: php, salesforce

I'm creating a lead form for my site. I want to store the data locally and in Salesforce.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $leads = array($_POST["myValue1"], $_POST["myValue2"], $_POST["myValue3"],
     $_POST["myValue4"], $_POST["myValue5"], $_POST["myValue6"], 
     $_POST["myValue7"], $_POST["myValue8"], $_POST["myValue9"], 
     $_POST["myValue10"] );

$qry = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO leads (myValue1, myValue2, myValue3, myValue4, myValue5, 
     myValue6, myValue7, myValue8, myValue9, myValue10) 
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$qry->execute($leads);

//I want to send the array $leads to Salesforce at this point
```

Currently, I am using the following to send data to Salesforce via web to lead

```
<form name="MyForm" id="MyForm" method="post" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" >        
<input type=hidden name="oid" value="SALESFORCE VALUE GOES HERE">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.mysite.com/thank-you">
<input type=hidden name="lead_source" value="web">
<input type=hidden name="Campaign_ID" value="SALESFORCE VALUE GOES HERE">
<input type=hidden name="recordType" value="SALESFORCE VALUE GOES HERE">
}
```

So basically, how can I fire off a `$_POST` after I store the data locally? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
$responce = curl_exec( $ch );
//debug
$err      = curl_errno( $ch );
$errmsg   = curl_error( $ch );
$header   = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```